# Como recuperar index de combobox a partir de uma string?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Tenho a String referente a um item do combobox, mas quando o usuário clicar na tabela, o combobox deve selecionar automaticamente a categoria daquele certo item. Porém, me deparei que não existe a função getIndex of como coloquei abaixo. Como posso recuperar o index a patir dessa string?

```
private void TabelaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    // Click na tabela para selecionar produto:
    if (Tabela.getSelectedRow() != -1){

        txt_descricao.setText(Tabela.getValueAt(Tabela.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
        cb_marca.getIndexOf("teste");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como está utilizando o [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html), o método para recuperar o índice de um item caso ele exista no combo é através do método [`getIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#getIndexOf-java.lang.Object-):

```
((DefaultComboBoxModel)seucombo.getModel()).getIndexOf(anObject);
```

Apenas destacando que ele retorna `-1` se o objeto não for encontrado entre os itens do ComboBox.

Comment: Eu não tenho o indice do item so tenho o que ele vale exemplo

Comment: Item1, Item2, Item3 - preciso de algo assim: getIndexOf("Item2) e isso me deve retornar o numero 1 que seria o indice desse item

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro seu combo possui um comboboxmodel customizado?

Comment: Estou usando o modelo dafault de comboBox

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro veja a edição.

Comment: Agora sim deu certo muito obrigado

Comment: O algoritmo de ranking do google se baseia em links. Assim sendo, sugiro só colocar links para o Javadoc do Java 9 a partir de agora e atualizar os antigos também, para que todos caiam nas referências mais novas e o google a coloque mais acima em relação às mais antigas.

Comment: O link do `getIndexOf` está apontando para algo que não é o `getIndexOf`